# Aggregate data based on dates

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is a similar structure to this:

```
account_no <- c(1:5, 2, 2 , 3)
interaction_date <- c("1/1/2016","2/5/2016", "3/2/2016",       "27/4/2016","11/10/2015",    "11/10/2015","11/10/2015","2/5/2016")
interaction_date<- as.Date(b, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
action <- c("a","c","b","c","c","a","a","b")
df <- data.frame(account_no ,interaction_date, action)
df
```

There are a couple of other attributes associated with each row, but this is the typical structure.

Essentially it is log data, describing interactions of a user (account_no), the time they interacted and the action they took.

I've been told to find underlying trends in the data.
Is there a way I can aggregate the data based on account_no that would give me an insight into the average length in days between interaction dates?
Or some sort of count to see what is the most common action taken on a specific day?
There are about 80,000 rows in the dataset, and there may be a number of actions on the same account on the same day. Is there a way in which I can break this down into something meaningful?

Comment: You might get more help if you provide the desired answer for the example data set.  Without that information one person has already voted to close your post, probably because it is not clear what you are asking.  Also, your code does not run.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get a sense of the gap between interaction dates:

```
df$interaction_date <- as.Date(df$interaction_date,'%d/%m/%Y'); ## coerce to Date
df <- df[order(df$interaction_date),]; ## ensure ordered by interaction_date
aggregate(cbind(gap=interaction_date)~account_no,df,function(x) mean(diff(unique(x))));
##   account_no gap
## 1          1 NaN
## 2          2 204
## 3          3  89
## 4          4 NaN
## 5          5 NaN
```

Only accounts 2 and 3 had 2 or more interactions, so the remainder get an invalid result. The `gap` unit is days between interaction dates.

I added the `unique()` call to exclude multiple interactions on the same date, since I assumed you wouldn't want those to lower the averages.

Answer (score 0):

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, interaction_date := as.IDate(interaction_date, "%d/%m/%Y")]
df[order(account_no,interaction_date), .(Gap = mean(diff(interaction_date))) ,account_no]
#   account_no      Gap
#1:          1 NaN days
#2:          2 102 days
#3:          3  89 days
#4:          4 NaN days
#5:          5 NaN days
```